# Choicepoint pruning needs a cut, but I think the compiler should be sharp enough to do it by itself

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-cut

I'm doing an exercise of writing a `between/3` that takes an additional step value.

This is an interesting exercise, quickly showing:

- the advantage of tagged integers (i.e. use `pos(X)` instead of `X` if `X` is a positive integer to take advantage of pattern matching)
- the magic inherent in making the predicate as deterministic as possible (do not leave a choicepoint open at the end of the sequence)
- the interest in passing a "flag" array to the predicate to fine-tune behaviour (in this case, should it throw or fail if the sequence is empty?)

But also:

- the less than well-thought-out format of the ISO standard exception terms (using compound terms instead of lists to ferry info ... WTF!)
- the naming of the exception-throwing predicates in `library(error)` (why not call them `throw_...` instead of confusingly giving them the same name as the exception term, will people really want to `call(domain_error(...))`?
- the fact that `must_be/2` cannot take additional position information about which arg exactly caused a problem (why!)

The complete code is [between_with_step.pl](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/code/between_with_step.pl) ... not yet fully unit tested.

Now I have set up the following predicate

```
between_enum(+Start,+TaggedEnd,+TaggedStep,-Value)
```

which emits the next value of the increasing or decreasing sequence of integers. It uses pattern matching of tagged values. In particular, the case "end value if the sequence is an integer" (as opposed to an atom denoting *infinity*) and "the step is positive" is given by the following subset of clauses matching the terms `int(End)` and `pos(Step)`:

```
% ---
% Case of "positive step" pos(Step) and "integer end" int(End) (not infinite end)
% ---

% Past end of sequence. Occurs only if the sequence is empty on entry.

between_enum(Start,int(End),pos(_),_) :- 
   Start > End,!,fail. 

% Last entry in sequence, emit "Start" as "Value" and don't allow backtracking!
% The test "Start < End" is redundant here.

between_enum(Start,int(End),pos(Step),Start) :- 
   Start < End, Start+Step >  End, !. 

% More entries exist in sequence, emit "Start" as "Value" and DO allow backtracking!
% The test "Start < End" is redundant here.
% The test "Start+Step =< End" is redundant here, being the complement of the cut-off preceding clause

between_enum(Start,int(End),pos(Step),Start) :-
   Start < End, Start+Step =< End.    

% Recursive alternative to the above, digging for more values!
% The test "Start < End" is redundant here.
% The test "Start+Step =< End" is redundant here

between_enum(Start,int(End),pos(Step),Value) :-
   Start < End, Start+Step =< End, 
   NewStart is Start+Step, 
   %!, % NEEDED TO MAINTAIN DETERMINACY ON LAST VALUE
   between_enum(NewStart,int(End),pos(Step),Value).
```

Now, to be fully deterministic at the end of the enumeration, the following clause needs a cut:

```
between_enum(Start,int(End),pos(Step),Value) :-
   Start < End, Start+Step =< End, 
   NewStart is Start+Step, 
   !, % <---- HERE
   between_enum(NewStart,int(End),pos(Step),Value).
```

Otherwise:

With cut:

```
?- between(10,15,1,Value).
Value = 10 ;
Value = 11 ;
Value = 12 ;
Value = 13 ;
Value = 14 ;
Value = 15.        % This is the end for sure!
```

Without cut:

```
?- between(10,15,1,Value).
Value = 10 ;
Value = 11 ;
Value = 12 ;
Value = 13 ;
Value = 14 ;
Value = 15 ;      % Unsure whether this is the end?
false.            % Well, turns out it is the end, really!
```

Shouldn't the compiler be muscular enough to determine that no further matches are possible after `between_enum(Start,int(End),pos(Step),Value)` - this being the last one in the series tagged with

- `int/1` on 2nd position and
- `pos/1` on third position?

This SWI-Prolog 8.1.

**Edit**

Could be that the compiler just indexes on the first two arguments. There is a no need for a cut in

```
between_enum(Start,int(End),neg(Step),Value)
```

which is followed only by

```
between_enum(Start,inf,neg(Step),Value)
```

as well as

```
between_enum(Start,minf,neg(Step),Value)
```

And so it can bloody well distinguish `inf`, `minf` and `int(_)`.

Comment: SWI's indexing is described at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex. It claims to do indexing over multiple arguments and mentions a predicate `jiti_list/1` that supposedly tells you about the way a predicate is indexed. The docs don't say how new this feature is, it's not present in my ancient 7.2.3 version.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Thanks Isabelle, I will take a look.

Comment: ISO-style exceptions *do* offer what you want. Exception terms always have the form `error/2`. The first argument are terms lin the form of `instantiation_error/0` or `syntax_error/1` or `domain_error/2`. The second argument is available for conveying more information in any style you choose. In general, more is less here, though.

Comment: @repeat Yes, but ... sadly the throwing function of library(error) do not allow to set that parameter. I just want to pass a dict! (Why should "more be less" though? It's just another term, the size of which really doesn't matter - unless one is throwing relentlessly for some reason)

Comment: If you want more than this library offers, use `throw/1` directly. Keeping it simple is good in general. Do one thing and do it well... the UNiX way!

Comment: @repeat Roger that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Prolog system dependent, and depends on the available automatisms for indexing or on the available directives for indexing. For example SWI-Prolog has automatic deep indexing, but some idiosyncrasies concerning automatic multi-argument indexing. So for the example from madgen:

```
first(tag1(_),_).
first(tag2(_),_).

second(_,tag1(_)).
second(_,tag2(_)).
```

I get in my system, both queries do not leave a choice point:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 4, Runtime Library 1.4.7

?- first(tag1(1),2).
Yes

?- second(2,tag1(1)).
Yes
```

On the other hand in SWI-Prolog, a choice point is left in the second query:

```
SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.17)

?- first(tag1(1),2).
true.

?- second(2,tag1(1)).
true ;
false.
```

This can be quite annoying, and often facade predicates need to be
used to reorder the arguments, to make them more suitable to the
SWI-Prolog specific indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition about parameter order is correct and can be confirmed with a simple experiment.

```
first(tag1(_),_).
first(tag2(_),_).

second(_,tag1(_)).
second(_,tag2(_)).
```

```
?- first(tag1(1),2).
true.

?- second(2,tag1(1)).
true ;
false.
```